# Compare two dates in JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date

I want to compare the user's birthday against today's date and get the number of days in between. The birthday they enter will be in the form of *12/02/1987* in an input box of type *text*

In my JS file I have code that looks like this:

```
function validateDOB(element) {
var valid = false;

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //do that January is NOT represented by 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
}
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
}

var today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
alert(today);
if (element.value != today) {
    var days = 0;
    var difference = 0;

    Christmas = new Date("December 25, 2011");

    today = new Date();

    difference = today - Christmas

    days = Math.round(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)-1);
    alert(days); 
    valid = true;
}
```

Instead of using "Christmas" I want to compare `element.value`... how do I do this?

When I put `difference = today - element.value` it won't show me the difference. The alert box comes up as `NaN`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare 2 dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-2-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: @widor no, my Q is specific...

Comment: Your question is specific, yes, but that question answers it.

Comment: @Blender - The real question (despite its title) seems to be "Why does `difference = today - element.value` return `NaN`?".  The linked question is trying to determine if one date is greater than, less than, or equal to another date.  This question is about determining the number of days between two dates.  The date comparison is already being done correctly here so that answer doesn't really help.  The real answer is to parse the string to a Date before comparing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate number of days between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to first parse `element.value` as a date:

```
difference = today - new Date(element.value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/3DKfy/

Answer (score 142):

I wrote a lightweight date library called [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to handle stuff like this.

```
var birthday = moment('12/02/1987', 'MM-DD-YYYY');
var inputDate = moment(element.value, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
var diff = birthday.diff(inputDate, 'days');
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: not sure how well "lightweight" aged (https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3376). Also, https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/